# Microsoft Word Sentence Length Checker

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm trying to implement code I found for Word that will check sentences and mark them in red if they exceeds 25 words (not equal to, or exceed - just exceed, so 26 words or more should be flagged).

The problem I'm having with this code is that it will mark sentences shorter than 25 words if you include commas in the sentence - this might also happen with other punctuation marks, but so far I've experienced it with commas specifically.

Here's the code:

```
Sub AutoExec()
    ‘ The AutoExec is a special name meaning that the code will run automatically when Word starts
    CustomizationContext = NormalTemplate
    ‘ Create key binding to change the function of the spacebar so that it calls the macro Check_Sentence
    ‘ each time the spacebar is pressed
    KeyBindings.Add KeyCode:=BuildKeyCode(wdKeySpacebar), _
    KeyCategory:=wdKeyCategoryMacro, _
        Command:=”Check_Sentence”
    ‘ It will be useful to be able to turn the checking on and off manually
    ‘ so allocate ctrl-shift-spacebar to turn the checking off
    KeyBindings.Add KeyCode:=BuildKeyCode(wdKeyControl, wdKeyShift, wdKeySpacebar), _
        KeyCategory:=wdKeyCategoryMacro, _
        Command:=”SetSpaceBarOff”
    ‘ and allocate ctrl-spacebar to turn the checking back on
    KeyBindings.Add KeyCode:=BuildKeyCode(wdKeyControl, wdKeySpacebar), _
        KeyCategory:=wdKeyCategoryMacro, _
        Command:=”SetSpaceBarOn”
End Sub

Sub SetSpaceBarOn()
    KeyBindings.Add KeyCode:=BuildKeyCode(wdKeySpacebar), _
        KeyCategory:=wdKeyCategoryMacro, _
        Command:=”Check_Sentence”
    MsgBox (“sentence length checking turned on”)
End Sub

Sub SetSpaceBarOff()
    With FindKey(BuildKeyCode(wdKeySpacebar))
        .Disable
    End With
    MsgBox (“sentence length checking turned off”)
End Sub

Sub Check_Sentence()
    Dim long_sentence As Integer
    ‘ pressing the spacebar calls this macro so have to assume the user wanted a space to appear
    ‘ in the text. Therefore put a space character into the document
    Selection.TypeText (” “)
    ‘Set number of words to be a long sentence
    long_sentence = 25
    For Each Test_Sentence In ActiveDocument.Sentences ‘ check each sentence in the document
        If Test_Sentence.Words.Count > long_sentence Then ‘ if it longer than our limit
            Test_Sentence.Font.Color = wdColorRed ‘ turn the font for the sentence red
            ‘ Test_Sentence.Font.Underline = wdUnderlineDotted ‘ show long sentences with a dotted underline
        Else
            Test_Sentence.Font.Color = wdColorBlack ‘ if less than our limit make the font black
            ‘ Test_Sentence.Font.Underline = wdUnderlineNone ‘ turn of the underline
        End If
    Next ‘ next sentence
End Sub
```

Hoping someone here can suggest how to revise the code to avoid these issues and help this perform the way it's intended!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Proper indenting of code and ensure that the line breaks are in the right place makes the code easier to read and makes it easier for other to provide an answer.

Comment: Not an answer to your direct question - but consider the cost in time. Each time a user changes a sentence (adds the space), you then check every sentence in the document. Why not only check the sentence they are working on?

Answer (score 2):

I would split the sentence myself, and count the number of words.

This functions returns `True` if the sentence `s` has 25 words or more

```
Function IsMoreThan25Words(ByVal s As String) As Boolean
    Dim words() As String, i As Long, WordCount As Long
    s = Replace(s, ".", " ")
    s = Replace(s, ",", " ")
    s = Replace(s, ":", " ")
    words = Split(s, " ")
    For i = LBound(words) To UBound(words)
        If Len(Trim(words(i))) > 0 Then WordCount = WordCount + 1
    Next
    IsMoreThan25Words = WordCount >= 25
End Function
```

Note that I hard coded `,`,`.` and `:` as delimiters, feel free to change that

Comment: I would replace `Integer` with `Long`, now it's a guaranteed `Overflow` error on big documents.

Comment: Do be aware that VBA has no idea what a grammatical sentence is. For example, consider the following:
*Mr. Smith spent $1,234.56 at Dr. John's Grocery Store, to buy: 10.25kg of potatoes; 10kg of avocados; and 15.1kg of Mrs. Green's Mt. Pleasant macadamia nuts.*
For you and me, that would count as one sentence; for VBA it counts as 5 sentences.